# How can I prove that an individual was possessed during the act of committing a crime?

Tags: law, crime

Devils are alive, and walk among us. This has been known to the human civilization ever since the gates to hell opened up, releasing the Devils upon our world. Although the gate was sealed and the Devils vanquished, it has weakened the barrier between worlds. This allows strong or oppurtunistic devils to cross over through "holes" that periodically open up as spirits to possess humans.

When a devil takes over a human, they become passengers in their own body, but are still aware of the internal war that is going on. There are certain changes that become notable while under possession. Their pupils glow red, strength and speed increase, and their endurance increases, allowing them to take numerous punishment without slowing down or being killed. There are three ways in which a human can be freed. First, the individual is killed, sending the devil back to hell. Second, the spirit leaves willingly, which they sometimes do when they are backed into a corner. Finally, a devil can be excorcised from the body through a dangerous, ancient excorcism that can potentially kill the victim.

I am a Pheonix Wright, a defense attorney hired to represent a serial killer who was possessed by a devil and forced to commit horrible crimes. The devil left his body after it had its fun and knew it was about to be caught. The individual is being charged with eleven homicides, which normally would not be a big deal. However, he is also being linked to a gruesome crime of kicking two puppies while jaywalking, a despicable act which has made this a death penalty case.

I cannot exactly bring the demon into a court room for cross-examination. Naturally nobody is going to just take the defendant's word for it that he was not in control over his body at the time of his actions. How can I go about proving that my defendant was possessed during his crimes and that "a devil made him do it"?

Comment: Why not allow a suitably skilled occultist to call up that demon for questioning? That's definitely a recipe for an entertaining trial... (The demon has a built-in incentive to cooperate: it wants to clear its name, or a jury might take its reticence as evidence that the man *was* possessed)

Comment: Nothing to prevent you being called Pheonix. Just be aware that the usual spelling is *Phoenix* ;-)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(mythology)

Comment: If devils were a real part of the world, then societies, including law, would adapt to the new normal: The crime lab would detect residual ectoplasm at the crime scenes, brain scans of the alleged perpetrator would show classic recent-possession-trauma, the police occult-detective would get otherworld confirmation and perhaps the demon's name, etc. Those poor puppies.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question. There is sufficient information in the question to apply aspects of demon possession as proof. The glowing red eyes & enhanced strength and speed are clues. This is part of the world. It follows proving possession is an element of this world & its legal code. I recommend the VTCers to reread Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way of proving his possession is looking for footage from **surveillance cameras** in the surroundings of the crime scenes, the work place and home of your client or **smart phone videos or photos** of your client during the time of possession. Apparently, the demon has been in possession of the "victim's"/murderer's body for several days, if not weeks or months to commit so many crimes, so the chances are almost 100% in a society as advanced as ours that a photograph or video with his eyes visible has been made. **Pupils do not just appear red**, as in photographs when the light in reflected on the retina, they actually

> "glow red"

making that a clearly discernible effect. This allows your client to prove that he had been possessed by a demon and also provide a time frame for this possession.

Answer (score 2):

Remainings of the dark aura of the devils in the body can trace us for how long, how long ago and how severe the victim has been possessed:

The longer the spirit possessed the furthur are remainings in the bone. This happens due to  aura can flow through organics, but not through bones (like x-Ray). The longer the spirit possessed the victim, the further gets the aura through the bone.

The severeness comes from the strength (power) of the devil. A strong devil can control the victim completely, while a not so strong can just control the victim periodicly or when the victim lacks mental strength, or the devil can just 'whisper' to the victim or manipulate the victims emotions.
The 'heavier' the victim is possessed the more the body adapts to the aura, changing the victims body to be more infernal. This also affects the bones, making the bones stronger over time, making the whole body stronger to be better at the hunt. Eventually we see even in the most severe cases even the beginning of one or two horns at the skull. But just the outer bone layers get stronger, the inner are spared, because the aura can't reach them instantly.

The how long ago can be seen when we calculate, how strong the bone is and how far this strength goes inside the bone.

You definetly ask how can we detect the aura? First we don't have to detect the aura or a slight red glow (see @alex2006's answer). We can detect it by the strongness of the bone. In an operation the victim's arm will be pierced with a fine drill, which can measure the pushing pressure that is needed to pierce the bone. With the results you can measure the severeness of the whole possession and how long the time from the infestation to the release needed.

A story how this could be found out:
The doctors may notice a bullet which was shot through the victims leg and was stopped by the bone splinting a bit. But the investigators find out the bullet should have pierced the whole leg with bone.

Hope this helps :)

PS: The deformation of the body might not turn back, but leave the MC with a way to become a super hero